# How to run Airflow PythonOperator in a virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, airflow

I have several python files that I'm currently executing using BashOperator. This allows me the flexibility to choose the python virtual environment easily.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

default_args = {
   'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    ...}

dag = DAG('python_tasks', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="23 4 * * *")

t1 = BashOperator(
                 task_id='task1',
                bash_command='~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/python 
                              /python_files/python_task1.py',
                 dag=dag)
```

How can I achieve the same using PythonOperator to something like this?

```
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import PythonOperator
import python_files.python_task1

python_task = PythonOperator(
              task_id='python_task',
              python_callable=python_task1.main,
             dag=dag)
```

I assume PythonOperator will use the system python environment.
I've found that Airflow has the PythonVirtualenvOperator, but this appears to work by creating a new virtual env on the fly using the specified requirements. I'd prefer to use an existing one that is already properly configured.
How can I run PythonOperator with a specified python path?

Comment: The PythonOperator simply runs callables. You will need write a specialized operator class that subclasses PythonOperator class to do use a pre-defined python virtual environment.

Answer (score 14):

My work-around is to use a Bash Operator to call `/path/to/project/venv/bin/python my.py`

Answer (score 11):

First things first: you should not (in general) rely on pre-existing resources for your Operators. You operators should be portable, so using longstanding virtualenvs is somewhat against that principle. That being said, it's not as much of a big deal, just like you have to preinstall packages to the global environment you can pre-bake a few environments. Or, you can let the Operator create the environment and subsequent operators may reuse it - which is, I believe, the easiest and most dangerous approach.

Implementing a "virtualenv cache" shouldn't be difficult. Reading the implementation of [`PythonVirtualenvOperator`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/python_operator.py#L242)'s execution method:

```
def execute_callable(self):
    with TemporaryDirectory(prefix='venv') as tmp_dir:
        ...
        self._execute_in_subprocess(
            self._generate_python_cmd(tmp_dir,
                                      script_filename,
                                      input_filename,
                                      output_filename,
                                      string_args_filename))
        return self._read_result(output_filename)
```

So it looks like it doesn't delete the virtualenv explicitly (it relies on [`TemporaryDirectory`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/utils/file.py#L27) to do that). You can subclass `PythonVirtualenvOperator` and simply use your own context manager that reuses temporary directories:

```
import glob

@contextmanager
def ReusableTemporaryDirectory(prefix):
    try:
        existing = glob.glob('/tmp/' + prefix + '*')
        if len(existing):
            name = existing[0]
        else:
            name = mkdtemp(prefix=prefix)
        yield name
    finally:
        # simply don't delete the tmp dir
        pass

def execute_callable(self):
    with ReusableTemporaryDirectory(prefix='cached-venv') as tmp_dir:
        ...
```

Naturally, you can get rid of the `try-finally` in `ReusableTemporaryDirectory` and put back the usual `suffix` and `dir` arguments, I made minimal changes to make it easy to compare with the original `TemporaryDirectory` class.

With this, your virtualenv won't be discarded but newer dependencies will be eventually installed by the Operator.

Answer (score 0):

Use PythonVirtualenvOperator. You need to provide a python function to be run and a requirements.txt of the virtual environment.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).