# How do I run python in a conda environment with airflow?

Tags: anaconda, airflow

conda 4.10.1
airflow 2.2.2

I normally run a script in the following manner

```
conda activate env
python /path to script/script.py
```

So I put those two commands into a bash script and used the bashOperator like so:

```
t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id='testtask',
        depends_on_past=False,
        bash_command='/path to bash/script.bash ',
        retries=0,
    )
```

and got the dreaded conda is not setup to activate environments.

Then I did:

```
conda init bash
conda activate env
python /path to script/script.py
```

but of course, the shell has to be restarted, which I don't know how to do in apache airflow.  There has to be default args or something secret with the .bashrc etc. to activate anaconda environments in non interactive mode, but I'm a windows conda transplant and a tutorial is not handy.

There's this other solution which basically does a bunch of tricky things to start python in the environment of your choice,
[How to run Airflow PythonOperator in a virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738173/how-to-run-airflow-pythonoperator-in-a-virtual-environment/58440405#58440405)

That secret hack is to just run the python in the environment:

```
bash_command='~/anaconda3/envs/env_of_choice/bin/python 
                              /python_files/python_task1.py',
```

This guy was able to do it on anaconda 3.9!

[How to change working directory and specify conda environment in Apache Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66122360/how-to-change-working-directory-and-specify-conda-environment-in-apache-airflow)

But mysteriously, my environment and my base environment have the same python.  When I type env for both environments the difference is in the following:

```
conda_shlvl=2 instead of 1
conda_prefix_1 = users/me/opt/anaconda3
path includes /users/me/opt/anaconda3/envs/env_of_choice/bin
conda_prefix=/users/me/opt/anaconda3/envs/env_of_choice
conda_default_env=sfdc
```

There are a few ways to go.  Maybe I didn't set up the environment correctly and its using the base python instead of making a python in the virtual environment.  I used a yml file.  It's also really tempting just to set these environment variables in the DAG, but maybe that's not the accepted way?  I couldn't find a tutorial. What's the right path?  Or maybe my version, 4.10.1 is too advanced and I should downgrade to 3.9.  Too many options.  Advice?

Answer (score 0):

The way I ended up doing this was to use the `conda run` command ([inspired from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72145492/conda-init-without-closing-the-current-shell)). conda run allows you to trigger a conda environment programmatically without needing to activate it - and this works within airflow.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at https://github.com/lynker-analytics/airflow-conda-operator for a convenient way of calling out to a conda/mamba environment:

```py
from airflow_conda_operator import CondaPythonOperator

# to be executed in the environment satellite-data
def load_geotiffs(data_location):
    # IMPORTANT: all imports inside the function
    import rasterio
    with rasterio.open(data_location) as img:
        # do something with it
        pass

# the operator will define the task in the airflow DAG
CondaPythonOperator(
    task_id="load_geotiffs",
    op_args=["s3://bucket/data.tif"],
    conda_env="satellite-data",
    expect_airflow=False,
    python_callable=load_geotiffs
)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).