# 'conda init' without closing the current shell

Tags: python, conda

There are a number of use cases for which  I am trying to use `conda` . The main headache is that `conda init` just does not want to play fair within the flow of a script ***in the same bash shell***. I frequently see

> CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.

That happens even though the contents of the conda initialize script as well as `conda init` have been executed.  The results are inconsistent: sometimes I have seen the init logic work, others not. I have not been able to ascertain what magic is happening and what it expects in order to work properly..

```
conda_init() {
    # __conda_setup="$('$CONDA_DIR/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)";
    source $CONDA_DIR/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
    export PATH="$CONDA_DIR/condabin:$CONDA_DIR/bin:$PATH";
    export CONDARC=$CONDA_DIR ;
    conda init bash
}
conda_init
conda activate py38
```

That gives us

```
 
/Users/steve/opt/miniconda3/bin/conda
/Users/steve/opt/miniconda3/bin::/Users/steve/opt/miniconda3/condabin:<other stuff..>

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

How can that `conda_init()` be made reliable for being able to run `conda init` in the same shell?

Comment: Where in the example here is `conda activate` called? Also, a lazy option would be to source the initialization file: `conda init bash && source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: @merv fixt the cut and paste error:  the `conda activate` is shown now.  This script is intended for use within a python script that might be running just about anywhere. The point is to dissociate from updating the user's home directories

Comment: Perhaps you might benefit from a proper standalone executable like [`micromamba`](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/micromamba.html), which includes activation functionality without touching users' resource files. Currently, the OP approach seems hackish to me and likely an XY problem. Consider describing in the question a production-stage vision of what ultimately is trying to be accomplished.

Comment: @merv  I am just completely beyond exhausted with these python environments having unexpected behavior.  Days of it.   I installed `micromamba`  now , did `micromamba install python=3.8 py38_mamba` and get `error    libmamba No target prefix specified` . No hits googling. I guess i can make another question on that one..

Comment: `Micromamba` documentation is insufficient for me to get an environment up and running

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, one should not need to "activate" an environment when working programmatically. That's what `conda run` is for...

```bash
conda run -n py38 python my_script.py
```

Otherwise, if `CONDA_DIR` is defined, then the following would run the initialization shell commands in an active bash session:

```bash
eval "$(${CONDA_DIR}/bin/conda shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
```

Comment: Ok i was unaware of `conda run`.  Will try that

Comment: Thanks for this answer about the `conda run`. I was using the Windows version of the second line: `conda shell.powershell hook | Out-String | Invoke-Expression`

Comment: @YtsendeBoer thanks. Any insight you have for Windows users is helpful. I don't run Windows and SO seems to lack a consistent pool of Conda+Windows answerers.