# Running Airflow DAGs in a separate virtual environment than the original base environment of Airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I am running Airflow in a separate virtual env and running a couple of data quality DAGs with specific requirements. Effectively I want to run the DAGs in their own virtual envs rather than cluttering the base Airflow environment.

*pythonVirtualenvOperator*  does somewhat similar but it creates its own environments every time and later removes them. A DAG that is run a couple of times a day is not efficient in time or space-wise.

I couldn't find a way to run the DAGs in a separate virtual environment in the same Airflow installation. Is there any way to do it

Answer (score 1):

What I do now is something like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58440405/7132596).

I basically have different conda-environments and explicitly call them using the Bash-Operator. Here is an example:

```
parse_my_files = BashOperator(
            task_id='parse-files',
            bash_command=f"{path_to_python} {abs_path_code}/my_repository/scripts/"
                         f"report_processing/pipelines/parse.py",
            env={"PATH": os.environ["PATH"],
                 "DB_URL": db_url}
        )
```

To install current packages, you need to activate the environment and run your package dependency resolver. For us, this is done using poetry

```
install_dependencies = BashOperator(
                    task_id=f"install-dependencies-{folder}",
                    bash_command=f"cd {abs_path_code}/{folder}; conda run -n {env_name} poetry install "
                )
```

It would be nice to have a python-operator that takes an environment and reuses it every time, but as I understand this is not on their to do list.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I am actually currently running this way, explicitly activating the environment and then running the DAG. As a stop-gap, this solves the issue but yes it would be good even if the pythonVirtualenvOperator could be run without creating new env

Answer (score 0):

@Saradindu Sengupta

Have you considered utilising the `DockerOperator()`? [Official Airflow Docker Reference](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/_api/airflow/providers/docker/index.html)

You could build an image with your specific requirements and execute via the DockerOperator.

Comment: yes and that would be an ideal production-level scenario but I wanted to run DAGs without the need for any containerization at this moment to make the dev process easier and faster